# Help identifying ceramic disc capacitor

Tags: capacitor, identification

I have a blue ceramic disc capacitor and I'm trying to work out the values. On one side of the disc are the following characters, in approximately this pattern:

```
  SHM
X 1400-
Y 1250-
E 222M
  F
```

The other side has a bunch of logos and symbols which I can't make out. I imagine the capacitor is 22 nF, but I'm trying to work out the working voltage is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a [South Hongming 2200pF E-grade Y5V X1(400V)/Y1(250V) safety capacitor](http://www.cnshm.com.cn/en/index.php?c=product&a=detail&id=586). The symbols are the numerous safety certifications the capacitor has.